# How can I do Sentiment Analysis using Weka on a PHP web?

Tags: php, machine-learning, weka, sentiment-analysis

I'm about to create a PHP website for Sentiment Analysis, and I wanted to use Weka for that. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide what have you tried , searched etc .. but Yes it's possible , have some look at these links :

[1] http://santini.se/teaching/sais/2016/SAIS2016_Assignment3_SA_Weka.pdf

[2] https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-do-sentiment-analysis-on-weka

[3] https://fr.slideshare.net/egidisa/sentweettwitter-sentiment-analysis-using-weka-and-java

it will help you to start in a first time !